# Condense jQuery Delegation Code

Tags: jquery, refactoring

Can someone help me condense this jQuery? Additionally, is there a way I can combine multiple $('body').on('click',....) so that I only need to run it once, but can list multiple selectors under that parent event.

```
$('body').on('click', '.tab2', function () {
    $('#tab1').removeClass('active');
    $('#tab2').addClass('active');
});
$('body').on('click', '.tab1', function () {
    $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
    $('#tab1').addClass('active');
});
```

Please note that the event is a class and inside the function are IDs. Here is the HTML I am using.

```
<a class="tab1">Hello</a>
<a class="tab2">World</a>
<div id="tab1" class="active">Something here for #tab1</div>
<div id="tab2">Something else goes here for #tab2</div>
<style>div {display:none;}</style>
```

Comment: Can you show your html also

Comment: Thanks everyone. Please note, that the click event is a CLASS and the elements inside the function are IDs. They both have the same name so it might be difficult to see. I will add the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have more classes in the `<a>` elements you can use this:

```
$('body').on('click', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('[class^=tab')) return
    $('div[id^="tab"]').removeClass('active');
    $('#' + event.target.className).addClass('active');
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GL6xJ/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this:

```
<div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
<div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
<div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
```

You can do it like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.tab', function () {
    $('.tab').removeClass('active'); //remove active from all tabs
    $(this).addClass('active'); //add active to clicked tab
});
```

Also, you can list multiple selectors using a `,` to separate them.

> $('body').on('click', '.class, .otherClass', function () {

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tab1">Content 1</div>
<div class="tab2">Content 2</div>
<div class="tab1">Content 1</div>
<div class="tab2">Content 2</div>
```

And Jquery...

```
$('body').on('click', '.tab1, .tab2', function () {
    $('.tab1, .tab2').removeClass('active'); //remove active from all tabs
    $(this).addClass('active'); //add active to clicked tab
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rg3V6/)

You can also make it more condensed... ie: "body" is assumed, so...

```
$('.tab1, .tab2').click( function () {
    $('.tab1, .tab2').removeClass('active'); //remove active from all tabs
    $(this).addClass('active'); //add active to clicked tab
});
```

[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Rg3V6/1/)